# Prove two sets are not equal. Discrete Mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, divisibility

Let $S=\{x\in\Bbb Z:\exists y\in\Bbb Z:x=24y\}$ and $T=\{x\in\Bbb Z:\exists y,z\in\Bbb Z:x=4y\land x=6z\}$. Prove that $S\ne T$.

Here's what I've done so far. I know that $S$ is a subset of $T$, but $T$ is not a subset of $S$. So $S$ cannot equal $T$. I am having trouble proving $T$ is not a subset of $S$.

suppose $x$ is in the set of $T$. Therefore $x$ is divisible by $4$ and $6$. How do I finish off this proof?

Edit: Consider $24 = 4y$ and $24 = 6z$. $y = 6$ while $z = 4$. $6$ can be rewritten as $2y' = 6$, while $2z' = 4$. This is the definition of even numbers.

I then get $y' = 3, z' = 2$. Now I substitute those values into the original equation. $x = 4(3)$ and $x = 6(2)$. both resulting in $12$. Have I shown in a valid way that the set $T$ contains factors of $12$, while set $S$ does not?

Comment: Can you think of a multiple of $4$ and $6$ that is not a multiple of $24$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial

Comment: Yeah its clearly 12, but how do I use mathematical proofs to show that

Comment: The proof does not have to **find** $12$, it just has to show that $12$ is a multiple of $4$ and a multiple of $6$ but not a multiple of $24$.

Comment: How does $A$ relate to $S$? I am assuming $A$ is a typo for $S$.

Comment: You are correct it is a typo. editing now

Answer (score 1):

If you have to show two sets are *not* equal, it suffices to find an element in one set and not the other. In this case, $12\not\in S$ but $12\in T$.

It turns out that $S\subsetneq T$, but this is not needed for the question at hand.